# What is the point to use useCallback in a component without React.memo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider example:

```
const Child = () => {
  console.log("I did re-render!");
  return null;
};

const App = () => {
  const [_, setValue] = useState();
  const fn = useCallback(() => {
    // do something
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(Math.random)}>click</button>
      <Child fn={fn} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

With every state change in `App` (click the button), the `Child` component re-renders, even if the passed prop `fn` is wrapped with `useCallback`. However, if I wrap `Child` with `React.memo`, it starts to work correctly - it does not re-render when parent re-renders.

My question: What's the point of using `useCallbacks` without `React.memo`?? Should I always use `React.memo` if I dont want the component to always re-render if its parent re-renders?

Should `useCallbacks` always be used with `React.memo`? Because it seems like they are senseless and useless without `React.memo`.

#### Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-khorana-nrojpb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Did https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback not explain what it's for well enough? You don't explicitly need `React.memo` when you use `useCallback`, it already yields a memoized function.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans if it yields a memoized function already, why does the child component re-render? The shallow comparison doesnt occur at all? Unless you use `React.memo`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The docs you linked say "*[It] is is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).*" So indeed, `useCallback` is not useful if the `<Child>` is not optimised by `React.memo` or `useMemo`.

Comment: Memoized functions don't prevent rerenders in any way, they just prevent "rerunning the _function_ to get its output data for rendering", only updating their value when a dependency of the function has changed. But in this case, the callback has an empty dependency list, completely negating the point of memoization, its dependencies will never change and it's basically a `const` with more code =)

Comment: So in the fact, `useCallback` is only useful when we want to avoid an endless loop in e.g. `useEffect` when passing the wrapped function as a dependency. In sake of avoiding children re-render, its completely pointless to use it without `React.memo`. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [React, when to use useCallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71265042/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

> My question: What's the point of using useCallbacks without React.memo??

There is none *unless* you otherwise tell React to compare based on refernece down the line.

> Should I always use React.memo if I dont want the component to always re-render if its parent re-renders?

Yes, or something equivalent.

> Should useCallbacks always be used with React.memo? Because it seems like they are senseless and useless without React.memo.

Yes, unless you do something equivalent.

---

Just to elaborate - other than `React.memo` you can always wrap a sub-render with `useMemo`:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [_, setValue] = useState();
  const fn = useCallback(() => {
    // do something
  }, []);

  const child = useMemo(() => <Child fn={fn} />, [fn]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(Math.random)}>click</button>
      {child}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or "roll your own" with useRef+useEffect *or* use class components and override `shouldComponentUpdate` or inherit from `React.PureComponent`.

Comment: There is one case where useCallback is useful without React.memo and thats when you want to call a function in a useEffect and dont want to add the function to the dependency array. Then you'd wrap the function in useCallback.