# Should I wrap this function in a useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a pretty decent understanding of how `useCallback` works. Figuring out when to use it though seems to be subjective amongst me and my colleagues though. I'm curious what everyone else thinks about our current dilemma.

Imagine we have a component that is dispatching an action to redux as a result of something being selected:

```
const SelectionComponent = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleSelect = (selection) => {
    dispatch(actions.updateSelection(selection))
  }

  return <Select onSelect={handleSelect} ... />
}
```

My colleague believes we should wrap `handleSelect` in a `useCallback` to make sure the function has a stable identity since it's being passed as a callback to a child component:

```
const SelectionComponent = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleSelect = useCallback((selection) => {
    dispatch(actions.updateSelection(selection))
  }, [dispatch])

  return <Select onSelect={handleSelect} ... />
}
```

So my question is, which is the better solution, and why?

Some notes:

- useDispatch returns a `dispatch` function with a stable identity
- No rerenders or performance issues occur without the useCallback

## EDIT

Just to clarify, this is a question on whether or not we should memoize a function on the basis of maintaining a stable identity when passed to a child component, even if the component tree is not expected to rerender for any reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use useCallback in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265042/when-to-use-usecallback-in-react)

Comment: no, the use case for using useCallback in that post is different.

Comment: Did you look at the answer? I think that it might help.

Answer (score 3):

Memoizing `handleSelect` only makes a difference if `Select` is memoized as well. Remember - when a component re-renders it also re-renders **all** of it's children by default (regardless of if their props change or not).

Therefore without knowing how `Select` is implemented, we can't really say if the `useCallback` actually has any affect much less if it is "better".

Usually, this type of optimization is unnecessary though. Unless your `Select` is complex or expensive in some way, you probably do not need to memoize either.

Answer (score 0):

same my question,
I just find the answer https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1468
"dispatch will be the same function reference the entire time. (In fact, in earlier versions of React-Redux, passing a new store reference was forbidden. We do now support changing it at runtime, but realistically you probably won't do that.)

However, the ESLint rule doesn't know that - it just knows that dispatch isn't a built-in React hook return value, so it might change, and therefore it tells you it should be added to the dependencies array just in case it ever does change."

Answer (score 0):

When component re-renders it re-renders all of its children, if any of their properties has changed. Meaning, if a child has the same properties as before, render is going to be triggered, it is true, but it won't actually make any changes and it won't take any time.

However, `useCallback` dependencies check is also comes with a cost, so it is for you to decide, would an overhead of using `useCallback` be cheaper than re-rendering your `Select` component. Considering that it also has other properties that may change and cause it to re-render.

I prefer to memoize callbacks unless they are passed to the "native" components. Because I can't be sure if a child component won't use this callback as a dependency.