# React useMemo and useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback, react-usememo

I have doubts about the usage of useMemo and useCallback

```
const componentName = () => {

...

const renderItems = () => elements.map(elem => <div> {elem.name} </div>

...
return (
   <div>
    {renderItems()}
   </div>
);
}
```

The first one is: Should I use the hook useCallback in the function renderItems?

The other question is in the case that I have an external file that exports a constant:

```
export const labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3"];
```

Should I use the hook useMemo on the variable labels that are located in a different file from the component?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is useCallback in React and when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265042/what-is-usecallback-in-react-and-when-to-use-it)

Comment: Why is `renderItems` a function at all? It makes it harder to visually parse the code, when it could just be inline.

Comment: renderItems will render a list of elements so if you make it a memoized then you are taking responsibility for updating it when it needs to be updated. Normally this responsibility should be passed on the React directly and you can leverage it better using [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) properties

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to use `useCallback` because no need to make it a function itself. The cleaner way to write this should be :

```
return (
   <div>
    {elements.map(elem => <div> {elem.name} </div>}
   </div>
);
```

But in any case:
`useMemo` is for values first of all and `useCallback` for function definition. With `useCallback` on the above code you are only saving the execution time of the function definition. The function will still run. If you want to memoize, you can memoize the output so the function runs only once like this:

```
const renderedJSX = useMemo(() => 
{
const val = elements.map(elem => <div> {elem.name}</div>);
return val;
},[elements]);
```

And then use it with your return statement:

```
return (
   <div>
    {renderedJSX}
   </div>
);
```

That way you are better of creating a new Component which takes `elements` as a prop and start using `React.memo`.

No matter which one you use you (`useCallback` or `useMemo`), you will have to use `elements` as a dependency. Once elements change your code will rerun. `elements` is an array so it will change in every render.

2. If the variables are scoped only to the react component you can keep them inside the function body. `memoize` if you want to using `useMemo` but that would be over kill for such a simple variable. Even if it is declared in a separate file, the code will only run once when it is parsed, so you don't have to worry about it.