# React Hook Form: display input content while user typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I created a React Hook Form and a `div` to display the data. I want to display the input value as a user type. I can do this with `onChange`, but I had a problem when I use `react-hook-form`.

If I tried to add `onChang`e after the `{...register()}`, it will work, but the error message will not go away if the input is empty. Is there a possible way to do this?

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const initalState = {
  name: "test",
  description: "test description"
};

export default function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(initalState);

  const handleFormSubmit = (data) => {
    setInfo(data);
    console.log(data);
  };

  const handleFormChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setInfo({
      ...info,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        <p>Name: {info.name}</p>
        <p>Description {info.description}</p>
      </div>
      <Form
        handleFormSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
        handleFormChange={handleFormChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const Form = ({ handleFormSubmit, handleFormChange }) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit)}>
      <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
      <input id="name" {...register("name", { required: "Can't be blank" })} />
      <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.name?.message}</p>
      <label htmlFor="description">Description: </label>
      <input
        id="description"
        {...register("description", { required: "Can't be blank" })}
      />
      <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.description?.message}</p>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subscription with [`watch`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) function returned by `useForms()`. For that, first change `handleFormChange` to:

```js
const handleFormChange = useCallback(
  (value, name) => {
    setInfo({ ...info, [name]: value[name] });
  },
  [info]
);
```

And then, in `Form` component, do this:

```js
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  watch,
  formState: { errors }
} = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) => {
    console.log(value, name);
    handleFormChange(value, name);
  });
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [watch, handleFormChange]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What is the benefit of using useCallback? Like do I need to use this when I get something from useEffect?

Comment: Glad I could help @Learning4Ever! About `useCallback`, it's not mandatory to have it here, but it would add some additional improvements to your app. If you wanna know what it does and when to use it, I would suggest this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265042/what-is-usecallback-in-react-and-when-to-use-it/71265201#71265201).